# Deeplinking: Can we use Route names outside route.config?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, deep-linking, routeconfig

I am working on deeplinking in ASP.NET MVC and using Angular JS. I have a doubt regarding that. When we specify Routes in RouteConfig.cs, can we access them outside that file to determine that if user is in deeplink or not?  How to build deeplink URL?

I am currently using `$rootscope.watch` to find the URL. Is there any other better way to do this?

```
$rootScope.$watch(function (newLocation, oldLocation) {
            if ($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation.indexOf('/SomeName/Deeplink/') > -1) {
            window.location.reload();
        }});
```

For example,

```
  routes.MapRoute("deeplinkurl", "SomeName/Deeplink/{SrcId}/{Id}", 
      new { controller = "SomeName", action = "Index" }, new String[] { "" });
```

I was thinking of using `routeconfig` instead of hard-coding the URL so, I would like to use `deeplinkurl` in `js` file or `cshtml`.

Comment: When writing your questions, there's a **{ }** symbol; that will format your code snippets, making them easier to read.

Comment: Format code snippets